# Button missing on live server

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot comprehend what is happening here, i wrote a button code on localhost server,it shows on [locahost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88sNb.jpg), but it does not show on [missing on live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k12g.jpg).  This is my code and I they are no cookies on my PC, i even tested it on my friends PC for the first time, no button showing.

```
<?php 
if ($_COOKIE['i'] == ''){
?>
<button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="z-index:1000;position:absolute;margin-top:-30px;height:30px;border-radius:0px;outline:none;background-color:#337ab7;border:0px!important;color:#fff;"> LOG IN/ SIGNUP</button>
<?php } else { ?>
<button>USERS NAME HERE</button>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: check if any of your php code is working on live server..

Answer (score 0):

If I go to look at your live page, the button *is* present on the page. However, CSS styling prevents the button from being displayed. The problem has nothing to do with the PHP code you posted.

So there still must be a difference between the live version and the one on your localhost - perhaps a different stylesheet?

Comment: yes @brain99 it is in the source code it present but don't know why it is not showing on localhost, there is no cookie like that on my PC or my friends either

Comment: As I said: if I go to the live page and view the HTML that is returned to my browser, the button *is there*, it's just that CSS makes it invisible. Has nothing to do with cookies. As to what is wrong with the CSS etc, I noticed there are other issues with the page (eg 404 on style.css) so you might want to look into that first